# Is every invertible matrix over an algebraically closed field diagonalisable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, diagonalization

In $\Bbb{R}$ the only invertible matrices (I can think of) that are not diagonalisable are those which stand for a rotation, but in $\Bbb{C}$ this shouldn't be a problem anymore, since rotations can be expressed via a multiplication with a complex scalar just fine.

So are there any invertible matrices over $\Bbb{C}$ that are *not* diagonalisable?

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I see my error in reasoning now: I still had orthogonal matrices in mind and the fact that _they_ consist of rotations and mirroring(?)... thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Spiegelung = reflection

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you want to post your comment as an answer, so I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: At the moment, I lack the energy to whip up a full answer. Anybody is invited to have a go.

Comment: Then I'll just refer to your comment, to close this thread–if you feel like it, you can still post one and of course I'll accept yours then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer) kindly pointed out in the comments there is a counterexample that works in $\Bbb{C}$ just like it does in $\Bbb{R}$:

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}

My error in reasoning was that I still had orthogonal matrices and their trait of consisting of rotations and reflections in mind.